# intel xdk update file remotely when app start

Tags: android, ios, html, intel-xdk

I want to create application locally for user who do not have internet connection so when user have connection and open application, the application will check update and the application update it from server.

For example like global petroleum show 2014 application.

I truly appreciate  your help in resolving the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can periodically do a conditional test for network access (such as on app startup), even [determining the connection type with the device API](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/493063).

Then use the [getRemoteDataExt method](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/493009), with an accompanying event listener to retrieve your remote data.

Finally, after processing your retrieved data, you can store it locally, most [easily using the cache API and its setCookie method](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/492841).

Then the most recently cached version of your data can be accessed at any time, with or without a network connection, through a simple getCookie call.

Comment: your option is so good btw can i use HTML5 Application Cache to my app?

Comment: Hi derylihs. It [looks like it may be possible](https://forums.html5dev-software.intel.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=5364) to use HTML5 Application Cache, but probably not recommended as this feature is blocked from the WebViews of some mobile platforms.  Probably much better to use [the XDK/Cordova Cache API](https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/xdkdocs#intel.xdk.cache) for storage purposes.  Feel free to accept my answer if you feel this has helped you get going.  Best wishes